# writing entire html file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I can't seem to find a way to write an entire HTML file via c#, I can only find something to write it line by line, but is there a way to add it all at once? Sorry for my bad English :(.
This is what I have at the moment:

```
string path = @"c:\MyTest.html";
// This text is added only once to the file. 
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    // Create a file to write to. 
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(@"<script type="text/javascript/">");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a string to a file using [`System.IO.File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376.aspx).

Comment: But how can I put javascript and quote signs in a string? It doesn't want to do it with quotes and other signs.

Comment: This seems to be a different question from writing to a file. Consider posting it as a new question.